# Would it be off topic asking on Stack Overflow why an R-package developer did something?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some years ago at university I frequently used the R-Package [Propagate V 1.0-4](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/propagate/versions/1.0-4) from [Andrej-Nikolai Spiess](https://www.rdocumentation.org/collaborators/name/Andrej-Nikolai%20Spiess). Today I needed it again at work, but after installing the package I noticed that the `contribution` function (which I particularly found very useful) was eliminated.

Would it be off-topic asking on Stack Overflow why an R-package developers took away that useful function in recent versions of their package, with the hope that somebody or maybe [Andrej-Nikolai Spiess](https://www.rdocumentation.org/collaborators/name/Andrej-Nikolai%20Spiess) himself could give me a satisfactory answer?

I know that I can get the function code I need from the [package source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/propagate/versions/1.0-4/source), but I still have the question about the why. Would it be better to write an e-mail directly to the developers?

Comment: It might be considered 'off topic' simply because I'm not sure how relevant that question will be towards the community. I've reached out to package creators via Github, so perhaps you could try that avenue.

Comment: Sounds like a _primarily opinion based_ question.

Comment: Ask for help with your *real* problem.  Which is not knowing why something disappeared, you want to know how to finish your program.

Comment: If I was in a similar situation, my Stack Overflow question (if I still needed to ask one after doing my own research) would be "I used to use this function to do this thing. Now that it's gone, how do I do the thing?" Why the function is gone may end up being part of the answer, but the main point is how to do the thing. (Kind of what Hans just said much more succinctly)